# Type 'Post[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Post[]>': error TS2322

Tags: angular, typescript

I have googled both the message and error and it seems the issue I keep finding is not what I am dealing with.

I am an angular noob and feel I am finally close to getting my service wired up.

I am getting the above error on my component

it will squawk at the `this.posts` below.

```
 getPosts() {
this.postsService.get()
  .subscribe((data: Post[]) => this.posts = data);};
```

and my service in case theres an issue there.

```
public get(): Observable<Post[]> {
return this.http
  .get<Post[]>(this.accessPointUrl);}
```

Someone save my morning please!

Comment: What type is `this.posts`? I'm guessing `Observable<Post[]>`?

Comment: Thanks for reading me back my own error Rahul...how do I remedy it?

Comment: @JeffLongo Change the type of `this.posts` from `posts: Observable<Post[]>` to `posts: Post[]`

Comment: I did that and while It will compile and run, I am getting 'undefined' in the console when I log out the posts object after.

Comment: oddly enough, in Augury, I can see the array with its contents...I am close, thats for sure

Comment: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe': that is my console error, when returning the Post instead of Observable

Comment: I would assume that means, I need to add an async pipe?

Comment: No, it means you need to remove your async pipe

Comment: hahaha, well I don't have one, so the plot thickens hahaha

Comment: Add pipe operator in your service - that will help `this.http.get<Post[]>(this.accessPointUrl).pipe();`

Comment: In that case, change the type back to `Observable<Post[]>`, and remove the `subscribe`, so it becomes `this.posts = this.postsService.get()`

Comment: I appreciate your help guys.
Adding the pipe to my service, let me compile with no errors, but still an undefined object...however I could see my array in augury again, but the data wasnt making it to the dom.

Changing it back to Observable and just using the .get() cleared all errors, but nothing logged in console and I have no array in my component.

Comment: worked for you ?

Comment: getting my angular debugging chops in this morning hahah

Comment: When you say it's logging undefined, where are you logging? Is it *inside* the subscribe function, or *outside*? Because the code is asynchronous, so if you try to log it outside of the subscribe function it will never work

Comment: just try to read the data in the completed function - the third arrow function in  `subscribe()` - try to read the data - hope it works - make sure you jump back to `this.posts : post[]` and try the above scenario

Comment: Thank you guys for your help...My code has been right probably several times over the course of the day...I never checked my template, and had left an ` | async` in one of my expressions, which was the issue...

Answer (score 0):

just return the http.

```
return this.http
 .get(this.accessPointUrl);}
```

Declare the type of `posts` as `post[]`

```
posts: Post[];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options you either change your `posts` variable to `Post[]`
or you dont subscribe to the `get()` method of your service and directly assign it to your observable variable like this:

```
this.posts = this.postsService.get();
```